# Full Page and scalable images for a Parallax Landscape page

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

So I have gotten this far with my idea:

http://skinnibones.herokuapp.com/

I'm using [scrolly.js](https://github.com/Victa/scrolly) for the parallax effect.

My two main problems are that I can't figure out **how to have the images be full-page, and scalable**.

I've tried adding `background-size:cover;` which gets rid of the yellow border I have but still doesn't make the images scalable since I have to specify the height of the images in px instead of as 100% which is what is required to make using cover work.

It also makes the parallax not as smooth as it currently is.

Any ideas how to make the images all scale and get rid of that yellow border that is being caused by the images not filling the browser fully?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is similar to what you have asked.  is it the same banner effect that is on the mediatemple website?

Comment: if you didn't had obfuscated css/js would help a lot :)